# two viewDidLoad messages when only one expected

Tags: ios, viewdidload

Can anybody think of why this line of code
    [self.view insertSubview:dataInputController.view atIndex:0];
would generate two viewDidLoad messages to the dataInputViewController followed by one viewWillDisappear and one dealloc?

I expected a single viewDidLoad with no viewDidDisappear or dealloc.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that `dataInputController.view` already had a superview? That would explain all calls.

Comment: I looked at _parentViewController for the dataInputController and it is nil both times viewDidLoad was called.  I did notice that the call stack is not what I expected.  The first time viewDidLoad is called the stack looks like this-- main, UIApplicationMain, UINibInstantiateWithOwner, switchViewController, UIViewController, UINibInstantiateWithOwner, dataInputViewController.  The second time viewDidLoad is called the stack looks like this--main, UIApplicationMain, UINibInstantiateWithOwner, switchViewController, UIViewController, dataInputViewController.  No 2nd UINib in the stack!

Comment: Check `[dataInputController.view superview]` just before doing the insert.